# IBM API Connect

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I would like to test IBM API Connect. I have a Lite account, but I cannot find the way to start a service.

I tried 2 ways:

1. I went to API Management > API Connect > Services and I found a funny message saying "There's no API Connect service. To start using the platform, click on Create service". But no Create service button is there.......
2. I went to Catalog > API Connect and in the new page I selected: Location: Frankfurt (because I'm in EU), Plan: Lite, and a message appears saying "You cannot use Lite plan with multiple locations".... but I have selected only one!!

What could I do? Is there something wrong in how I tried to create an API Connect Service?

Comment: Please consider asking the IBM support/forum.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your [resource list](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources) if you already provisioned it without knowing. Usually, only one free instance of a service is allowed.

If there is none, directly go to the [provisioning page for API Connect](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/api-connect).